# Django model attribute not updating

Tags: django

I'm trying to update the `bar` attribute of a couple of my `foo` model instances:

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    ...

    bar = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    baz = models.CharField()

    def updateBar(self):
        foo.objects.filter(baz='yes').update(bar=False)

    ...
```

But my tests keep failing:

```
def test_update_bar(self):
    a = Foo.objects.create(bar=True, baz='yes', ...)
    b = Foo.objects.create(bar=True, baz='yes', ...)
    a.updateBar()
    self.assertFalse(a.bar)
    self.assertFalse(b.bar)
```

I also tried to do it this way:

```
def updateBar(self):
    instances = Foo.objects.filter(baz='yes')
    for instance in instances:
        instance.baz = False
        instance.save()
```

But the tests fail all the same. Am I overlooking something?

I'm running Django 1.6.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 with a PostgreSQL 9.3.5 database

Comment: It looks like your `baz` is a charfield. Do you intend to do `self.assertFalse(a.bar)` ? MOreover, you are only setting the `bar` field, and `baz` still has the value `yes`

Comment: Whoops, my bad. fixed it

Comment: could you just put all the columns into the model so we can see what are you working with? Also the lowercase `foo` in `updateBar` is typo, right?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I hope this edit makes it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason this should work. Django model instances do not have identity - that is, separate instances are separate objects, even if they refer to the same database row. In your code, `a` and `b` are not the same objects as the various values of `instance` inside `updateBar`, because they come from separate database queries.

If you want to check that the db has indeed been updated, you need to re-fetch `a` and `b` after the modification:

```
a = Foo.objects.get(pk=a.pk)
b = Foo.objects.get(pk=b.pk)
self.assert...
```